# Scope of variable local to static method in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to create an instance of an object with private constructor. Is this method correct?

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
class A{
    int y;
    A(int y=2):y(y){};
    public:
    A(const A &obj){
        cout<<"copy Cotr is called"<<endl;
        this->y=obj.y;
    }
    int* addr(){
        int *a=&y;
        return a;
    }
    static A create(int y1=2){
        class A a(y1);
        cout<<&a<<endl;
        return a;
    }
    void print(){
        cout<<y<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    A o1=A::create(1);
    A o2=A::create(3);
    cout<<&o1<<" "<<&o2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0x7ffd20d2f280
0x7ffd20d2f284
0x7ffd20d2f280 0x7ffd20d2f284
```

In the above code, I fail to understand few points:

1. `create()` returns a value, so during assignment which take place in `A o1=A::create(1);`, copy constructor should be called but it isn't. why?
2. Is this some undefined behavior as the address of the object created in `create()` and in `main()` are same and the object in `create()` is local and goes out of scope after the function ends.

Comment: Look at (N)RVO (Named Return Value Optimization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. create() returns a value, so during assignment which take place in `A o1=A::create(1);`, copy constructor should be called but it isn't. why?

You have [copy-elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xY-G9r)) which is an optimization allowed by standard.

The object is directly constructed in final place and no copy/move is done.

Some copy-elisions is even mandatory in C++17. (half of them in your case).

> 2. Is this some undefined behavior as the address of the object created in create() and in main() are same and the object in create() is local and goes out of scope after the function ends.

With copy elision, as object is directly constructed in final place, there is indeed only one address, it is as-if the local variable of `create` was the one from `main`.

Comment: The copy elision of `a` into the return value of `create` is not mandatory, even in C++17. So half of the copy constructor calls may still remain: https://godbolt.org/z/iUdGSb

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
A a = x();
```

is different than this:

```
A a;
a = x();
```

In the second case you have a copy, in the first you don't.

To answer your second question, the object created in create() is local all right, but then it's copied back to the caller (actually, moved). Since the stack frame is the same, the local address is the same. But when it's copied, you have two different objects.

Comment: So it is like returning value and referance yield the same result?

Comment: Is it really "actually, moved"? Given the user-defined copy ctor, move ctor is not generated.

Comment: @r3musn0x it's neither moved, nor copied. As stated in the question's comments.

Comment: This answer is confusing, because (assuming there is no move constructor) `A a = x();` *may* copy in C++11. Only in C++17 is it guaranteed that this particular copy is elided. Then there is also the potential copy into the return value, which might not be elided even in C++17.

Comment: @walnut yes - I just wanted to simplify it because obviously the author need not get confused on copy/move/elision stuff. At this moment he is only interested to understand why the first line doesn't call the copy constructor.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis But sometimes it does call it, e.g. if I try the code with MSVC on https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual then only one of the two copies is elided. (I am not sure how old the compiler version used is, though)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. Dug deep into it and now answering my own question.

**For the learned:**

### This is major instance of copy elision in C++ 17.

*Answer ends for you. For the one who still didn't understood:*

This method has no errors and do not show any undefined behavior. Most of the compilers uses C++11 or C++17 these days which is well integrated with [copy elision(copy omission)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

> create() returns a value, so during assignment which take place in A
>   o1=A::create(1);, copy constructor should be called but it isn't. why?

Copy constructor is not called as the return type is [prvalue(pure rvalue)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) and the compiler optimizes the program in such a way that the return value is created directly into the storage where the function's return value  would otherwise be copied or moved to. So, actually no move or copy takes place so no move/copy constructor is called. Even after the end of `create()` destructor too is not called.

> Is this some undefined behavior as the address of the object created
>   in create() and in main() are same and the object in create() is local
>   and goes out of scope after the function ends.

So, even after the function `create()` ends, the object dont get pushed out of scope or the destructor for that object is not called. As the object is created in not in the `create()` but in the `main()` itself. It is not an undefined behavior but a major benefit of C++ as unnecessary pointers and functions need not to be declared or invoked. Here, **NRVO** takes place.

> - In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a
>     non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which isn't a
>     function parameter or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the
>     same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return
>     type. This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return
>     value optimization".